# Common Lisp: Working with &rest parameters

Tags: parameters, lisp, common-lisp

Can anyone tell me how to work with the parameters stored in the value specified by &rest.

I've read around a lot and it seems as if authors only know how to list all the parameters as so.

```
(defun test (a &rest b) b)
```

This is nice to see, but not really that useful.

The best I've found so far is to use first, second, and so on to get the parameter you are looking for.

```
(defun test (a &rest b)
    (first b))
```

I noticed this method stops working at the tenth parameter, but the specification (from what I've read) supports a minimum of 50. Even if the chances are slim that I'll use 50 parameters, I'd like to know how to access them all.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FIRST, SECOND and so on accessor functions are "just" utility functions on top of CAR/CDR or NTH. SO, I guess, the answer to your specific question is "use NTH or ELT" (or build your own specific acccessor functions).

If you want, you can define an ELEVENTH as:

> (defun eleventh (list)
>   (nth 10 list))

I find, however, that I mostly use &REST arguments when there's 0 or more things I want to do something with, not really caring about the specific position of a given argument in the &REST list. That usually entails using LOOP, DO or DOLIST to traverse the arguments and do something with each one; the MAP family or (occasionally) REDUCE.

Answer (score 8):

Rest parameter is just a list. You can handle it using normal list operations.

```
(defun test (a &rest b))
  (dolist (s b)
    (when (> s 1)
      (print s)
      (do-something-else b)))
```

Comment: It's a list inside the function, but passing a list as &rest might not give you the behavior you want (contrary to params[] from, say , C# language).
It's quite easy for a beginner (such as myself) to do this mistake: assume your function is recursive with a &rest parameter. Then during recursion you can't pass a list as the &rest param, you have to use apply #'yourfun...

Comment: @PawelP If you need to pass a list, then just use regular function param to pass that list. &rest params are just an easy way to invoke function with variable number of parameter without wrapping them in a list yourself on every call site.

Comment: What was misleading for me though was the fact that *inside* the function, &rest param is accessed just like a list, however you can't pass it directly as a &rest param recursively (because you'd be passing a list and it's probably not what you want). I think I'm not the only beginner who fell for this trap.
So it looks like LISP does some "packing" behind the scenes on function invocation (makes a list out of the params that are parsed as &rest)
Of course your explanation is correct, I'm not disputing that.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the function is useful. You only have to try it.

```
CL-USER 1 > (defun test (a &rest b) b)
TEST

CL-USER 2 > (test 1 2 3 4)
(2 3 4)
```

So you see that B is just a list of the arguments. So every list and sequence operation applies. There is nothing magic. There are functions to access the NTH element, functions to remove elements, etc..

In the Common Lisp HyperSpec the relevant functions are listed:

[14. The Conses Dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_conses.htm)

[17. The Sequences Dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_sequen.htm)

For a basic Lisp tutorial check out the book by Touretzky:

[Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/index.html)

The book is downloadable in PDF and Postscript. It teaches basic Common Lisp.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the gentle introduction. I've browsed through the first couple chapters and I have to say that I really wish this was the first programming book I read. It's very well done.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use destructuring-bind:

```
(defun my-function (&rest arguments)
  (destructuring-bind (a b &rest c) arguments
    (format nil "~A,~A followed with ~A" a b c)))

CL-USER> (my-function 1 2 "Give" 'me "more" 'arguments!!)
==> "1,2 followed with (Give ME more ARGUMENTS!!)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have a recursive iterate to go through them all, I guess dolist is better but I like using the old fashioned way